# Как можно заставить открываться test.example.com, как будто это example.com/?var=1 NGINX

Tags: apache, nginx, сервер, веб-программирование

Собственно хочется что бы сайт test.example.com работал точно так же как и example.com, но в случае с test.example.com невидимо (если что, можно и видимо) добавлялась GET переменная?

Пример:
Вводим example.com, открывается главная сайта.
Вводим test.example.com, открывается главная сайта, но существует GET переменная "var=1"

Вводим example.com/contacts, открываются контакты сайта.
Вводим test.example.com/contacts, открываются контакты сайта, но существует GET переменная "var=1"

Буду очень признателен за помощь!
Стоит nginx+apache2

Answer (score 5):

видимо:

```
server {
  server_name test.example.com;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?var=1 redirect;
}
```

невидимо:

```
server {
  server_name test.example.com;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?var=1;
}
```

Comment: плюс третий, независимсый вариант: проверять сервер в приложении и подтягивать конфиг согласно хосту

Comment: про третий независимый вариант ниче не понял.

За первые два наглядных примера спасибо!! Буду пробовать!!!
Спасибо!)

Comment: Это не то(
если ввожу test.example.com меня просто перебрасывает на example.com/?var=1

Нужно что бы в браузерной строке осталось test.example.com, а сам сайт думал что к нему обратились через example.com/?var=1

Comment: @MatthewPatell

> Нужно что бы в браузерной строке осталось test.example.com, а сам сайт думал что к нему обратились через example.com/?var=1

Там довольно красноязычные комментарии к обоим вариантам. Вам, очевидно, нужен "невидимо".

> про третий независимый вариант ниче не понял.

nginx и apache вообще слыхом не слыхивали про `var=1`, но в самом коде определяется текущий хост (example.com или test.example.com), и уже в зависимости от этого происходят какие-то действия (хоть прямо в `$_GET` устанавливаются произвольные данные).

Comment: да, нужен невидимый вариант.
Пока что так и не нашел как это сделать.

Comment: @MatthewPatell, а тот, который в ответе?

Вообще можно это дописать прямо в `try_files`:

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?var=1&$args;

Где $args будет содержимым оригинальной query\_string.

Comment: То, что в ответе, просто делает перенаправление.
Опять же, если вбить test.example.com, то перебросит на example.com?var=1
Нужно что бы с test.example.com не уходило, и работало как будто exaple.com?var=1
Где-то читал что делается через proxy_pass но увы, если так сделать, то и сам example.com начинает некорректно работать